# A classic StackOverflow : Java Swing

Tags: java, linux, swing

Greetings everyone!
I programmed GUI Application using Java Swing under Windows.

Under windows everything works well.

Now I am trying it under Linux (using distribution Linux Mint 7).

I am getting and nasty StackOverflowException, when I call **frame's dispose method**! The problematic frame is JDialog component.

Here is some output : edited, full output

```
 run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:261)
        at java.beans.Statement.invoke(Statement.java:231)
        at java.beans.Expression.getValue(Expression.java:115)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:227)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
        at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
        at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
        at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
        at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.j
```

Comment: I would encourage you to include the entire stack trace, even if it goes MUCH MUCH farther, because the elements listed here aren't sufficient to provide me with a clue of what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried using -Xss to increase the stack size? If you are using standard VMs it may be crashing because the linux has a smaller default stack size (of course it still seems odd that your stack would be getting that deep).

Comment: @jim - so there is full output :))

Comment: That is not full output.  You need the end too (but you can skip the repeated part)

Comment: Yeah, might be okay to omit most of the repeating bit: Just the top, bottom and repeating bit. Exact version numbers may also be useful.

Comment: Even better - can you compress the stack trace, showing the last lines, the refrain (the part that is repeated over and over), and the very first lines?. How many levels of recursion deep are you going (just count the number of repeats of the refrain)?. The first and the last lines of a stacktrace are always the most interesting ones...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possibility that I've ran into, make sure you are using the latest JDK/JRE from sun and not openJDK (which is default on some linux distros), which can occasionally cause hiccups like this.

Comment: Yes I do use OpenJDK, I am going to change it to defaut one

Answer (score 2):

Also it may be a good idea to check what you have called on your JFrame. To indicate that the JVM should exit when a frame is closed you could use

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

To me your error looks like the result of calling this API (or not calling or calling with wrongs args)
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)